# PHP Twitter Oauth login getting access_token manually

Tags: php, twitter, oauth

I'm working with an existing website! I have to integrate social registration! With Facebook and VK it's all clear. But I can't figure out the way Twitter works. 
I need the request token, but can't find the correct way, the correct link which could bring the user to twitter authorization page, after the authorization redirect , and fetch the request token. Any Ideas?

Comment: Please provide more details on what you have tried.

Comment: https://dev.twitter.com/web/sign-in/implementing

The thing is, I can't understand the STEP : 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll find this library well documented and shows end to end how to manage the request token: https://twitteroauth.com/

Comment: Thanks for the advise, but now I have another problem with the library!!!

the request_token and the access_token should match, it's in the documentations, but when i try it does't, and I get an error!! 

here it is "Uncaught exception 'Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuthException' with message 'Error processing your OAuth request: Invalid oauth_verifier parameter' "


ANY IDEAS?!!!